# Paypal Taxamt, SHIPPINGAMT, HANDLINGAMT does not work

Tags: paypal

i have a problem with paypal. i integrated it with with NAME, QTY, AMT, ITEMAMT.. and it works, but if i try to use taxamt,handlingamt or shippingamt it doesn´t work.
here is a code, i think it should work:

```
$padata =   '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE='.urlencode($PayPalCurrencyCode). // WÃ¤hrung
                '&PAYMENTACTION=Sale'.
                '&ALLOWNOTE=1'.
                '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0='.urlencode("Name").
                '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0='. urlencode(1).
                '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0='.urlencode(10).
                '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT='.urlencode(10).
                'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT='.urlencode(2).
                '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT='.urlencode(12).
                '&RETURNURL='.urlencode($PayPalReturnURL ).
                '&CANCELURL='.urlencode($PayPalCancelURL);
```

What is wrong? if i put AMT to 10 and delete the Taxamt it works... i hope you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you're missing an ampersand before `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT`.